# How to format a scraper output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to extrapolate the prices out of one site in order to create a scraper I wrote the program down below. In order to get all the html code i used BeautifulSoup and the default html.parser. then I tried cleaning up the information by using a variable called generale equals to soup.findAll("span"). then I need to clean up furthermore (the list (i suppose) it has been created) in order to get to the prices and I got stuck. Any suggestions? I do not know how to think in order to solve the problem

```
import smtplib

import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

import requests

URL = "https://www.allkeyshop.com/blog/buy-battlefield-5-cd-key-compare-prices/"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"}

def Check_page1():

    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')

    generale = soup.findAll('span')

    price = ?

    print(price)

    print(generale)

print(Check_page1())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the source code of the page you can see that you are looking for `<span>` with class name `price`, And it can be parsed this way:

```
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL = "https://www.allkeyshop.com/blog/buy-battlefield-5-cd-key-compare-prices/"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"}

def CheckPage1():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')

    # all spans with prices
    span_prices = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "price"})

    # to get all prices you need to extract text or content attribute
    for span in span_prices:
        price = span.text
        # remove whitespace and print price
        print(price.strip())

        # to get prices without money sign uncomment one of those lines
        # print(price.strip()[:-1])
        # print(price.strip().strip('€'))

CheckPage1()
```

Comment: Assuming that i just started coding with python and I don't know how all the parameters work, I have 4 other questions, how can I know how to properly use a command? And by formatting "soup.findAll("span", {"class": "price"})" what does {"class": "price"} actually used for? Is like find all "span" and then find class="price" between all the "span"? Why the curly braces? Meaning of the column in between? Sorry but I'm curious and I want to improve my knowledge

Comment: And another thing, you used the "for" "loop" in order to divide the single "spans", is possible to edit directly "span_prices"? what kind of variable is "span_prices" (i suppose a list)?

Comment: If you want to start parsing web you have to have some knowledge about HTML and CSS. So get inspiration in some of those web tutorials on internet. And if you do not know what curly braces means I would recommend you to watch/read some tutorials for python as well.

Comment: And for the answers:  **1**: command - you must know what you want to get from  the page then you try to find it. **2** It means find all `<span>` elements on given page that have `class="price"`. **3** something like that, yes. **4** curly braces - [dictionary in python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) **5** Colom is separator for paramers in function. See also [doc for bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)

Comment: What do you mean by edit span_prices? By using BeautifulSoup you can not modify (edit) the page. It is used for easy parsing of web to get your data quickly. And yes find_all returns list of all spans that matched given criteria (class name). And then you get the text from `<span>` by `.text`. Look around the internet also for some BeautifulSoup examples/tutorials. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've actually improved my program for all the games I want to see the prices.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a `<span class="price">`.
Here's what I did.

```
In [1]: import requests 
   ...:  
   ...: URL = "https://www.allkeyshop.com/blog/buy-battlefield-5-cd-key-compare-prices/" 
   ...:  
   ...: headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"} 
Out[1]: {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}

In [2]: page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)                                                        
Out[2]: <Response [200]>

In [3]: import re                                                                                        

In [4]: re.findall(r'<span.*?</span>', page.text)
```

There are a lot of spans. To me, the following looked most like prices.

```
 '<span class="topclick-list-element-price">10.56&euro;</span>',
 '<span class="topclick-list-element-price">2.79&euro;</span>',
 '<span class="topclick-list-element-price">2.90&euro;</span>',
 '<span class="topclick-list-element-price">27.86&euro;</span>',
 '<span class="topclick-list-element-price">11.15&euro;</span>',
 '<span class="topclick-list-element-price">11.46&euro;</span>'
```

So I refined the regular expression

```
In [7]: prices = [float(p) for p in re.findall(r'<span class="topclick-list-element-price">(.*)&euro;</span>', pag
   ...: e.text)] 

In [8]: print(prices)                                                                                    
[10.56, 2.79, 2.9, 27.86, 11.15, 11.46, 11.2, 18.67, 9.69, 24.25,
20.25, 19.59, 44.21, 28.3, 31.92, 41.39, 4.76, 24.57, 8.75, 28.62, 
27.14, 8.52, 31.95, 24.59, 27.93, 27.86, 5.5, 24.99, 37.99, 14.27, 
36.0, 8.75, 35.99, 37.34, 23.4, 22.98, 31.95, 36.89, 25.57, 27.9, 
35.88, 41.39, 33.22, 42.29, 31.29, 42.29, 38.09, 33.89, 33.59, 28.83,
10.56, 2.79, 2.9, 27.86, 11.15, 11.46, 11.2, 18.67, 9.69, 24.25, 
20.25, 19.59, 44.21, 28.3, 31.92, 41.39, 4.76, 24.57, 8.75, 28.62, 
27.14, 8.52, 31.95, 24.59, 27.93, 27.86, 5.5, 24.99, 37.99, 14.27, 
36.0, 8.75, 35.99, 37.34, 23.4, 22.98, 31.95, 36.89, 25.57, 27.9, 
35.88, 41.39, 33.22, 42.29, 31.29, 42.29, 38.09, 33.89, 33.59, 28.83, 
24.25, 12.11, 28.84, 37.36, 23.71, 2.19, 2.99, 34.25, 11.38, 14.99, 
20.67, 4.99, 25.56, 1.81, 12.99, 19.73, 9.99, 9.99, 0.92, 11.99, 
27.93, 22.94, 8.46, 32.78, 40.03, 11.19, 12.45, 13.29, 13.9, 26.22, 
26.22, 23.34, 25.22, 32.78, 37.36, 21.5, 19.01, 26.53, 24.91, 17.96, 
35.4, 17.05, 21.56, 16.39, 35.4, 8.98, 65.54, 13.45, 15.73, 22.39, 
17.99, 40.17, 8.0, 11.34, 14.99, 17.99, 10.99, 24.99, 22.41, 17.99, 
40.17, 7.2, 49.99, 41.1, 39.85, 16.99, 19.99, 21.99, 10.99, 19.73, 
14.99, 22.39, 6.55, 32.98, 27.99, 29.89, 19.99, 29.99, 37.36, 19.99, 
35.49, 15.99, 21.99, 46.71, 15.72, 42.97, 18.68, 18.87, 15.72, 19.99,
 29.99, 9.99, 28.02, 35.99, 39.99, 15.72, 15.72, 9.33, 44.48, 47.99, 
43.99, 47.99, 38.8, 23.27, 20.69, 44.6, 41.97, 15.75, 44.49, 19.87, 
51.99, 36.89, 15.99, 39.99, 27.99, 11.58, 43.99, 41.1, 19.99, 43.64, 
19.99, 36.89, 25.69]
```